# How to find where a value is stored in magento database

Tags: magento-1.8, eav

I have an extension that has allowed us to add some custom customer attributes to the database for use on their profile. I am looking to use one of the attributes ina  SQL join in an extension, but I can't find where exactly the value is being saved. I have found the description and setup of the attribute itself in the EAV_attribute table and the backend_type value for it is "varchar" but I can't seem to find exactly what table name to find the actual information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the values related to a specific customer in *customer_entity_varchar* table filtering out the dataset by attribute_id ( coming from *eav_attribute* you mentioned) and entity_id (in your case a valid *customer_id* ).